# How can I Monitor External files in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I  have a `.exe` file, It takes `.txt` file as a Input and it returns `.txt` files as outputs.

I have 2 folders names are `InputFiles` and `ExeFolder`.

`InputFiles` folder have so many number of input files, which files are passing as a argument to `.Exe` file.

`ExeFolder` have `.exe` file,`output` files and only one `Input` file(we will get this file from `InputFiles` folder).

I want to build 1 web Application, It will work in the following way.

step 1 :

it checks, How many no of files are available in sourceDirectory as far my requirements.generally every time I want to find `.txt` files but for my code maintenance I passed `filetype` as a argument to function.

For this,I wrote the following code,it's working fine

```
 public List<File> ListOfFileNames(String directoryPath,String fileType)
{
    //Creating Object for File class
    File fileObject=new File(directoryPath);
    //Fetching all the FileNames under given Path
    File[] listOfFiles=fileObject.listFiles();
    //Creating another Array for saving fileNames, which are satisfying as far our requirements
    List<File> fileNames = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < listOfFiles.length; fileIndex++) 
    {
        if (listOfFiles[fileIndex].isFile())
        {
          //True condition,Array Index value is File
          if (listOfFiles[fileIndex].getName().endsWith(fileType)) 
          {
              //System.out.println(listOfFiles[fileIndex].getName());
              fileNames .add(listOfFiles[fileIndex]);
          }
        }  
    }
    return fileNames;
}
```

step 2:

I used `for` loop Based on length of `ListOfFileNames[dir,filetype]`,For every Iteration `file` will be overwrite in `ExeFolder` folder. For this I wrote the following function.It's working fine

```
  public void FileMoving(File sourceFilePath,String destinationPath,String fileName)throws IOException 
 {
File destinationPathObject=new File(destinationPath);
if (
        (destinationPathObject.isDirectory())&&
        (sourceFilePath.isFile())
    )
    //both source and destination paths are available 
    {
        //creating object for File class
        File statusFileNameObject=new File(destinationPath+"/"+fileName);
        if (statusFileNameObject.isFile())
            //Already file is exists in Destination path
            {
                //deleted File
                statusFileNameObject.delete();
                //paste file from source to Destination path with fileName as value of fileName argument
                FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFilePath, statusFileNameObject);
            }
            //File is not exists in Destination path.
            {
                //paste file from source to Destination path with fileName as value of fileName argument
                FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFilePath, statusFileNameObject);
            }
    }
}
```

Step 3 :

`.exe` file will be run.For this I wrote the following function.Working fine but in this function I need to add some code for waiting.

```
   public void ExeternalFileProcessing(String DirectoryPath,String exeFilePath,String inputFileName) throws IOException
  {
//Creating Absolute file path of the executableFile
String executableFileName = DirectoryPath+"/"+exeFilePath;
//Assinging the InputFileName argument value to inputFile Variable
String inputFile=inputFileName;
//creating ProcessBuilderObject with 2 arguments
ProcessBuilder processBuilderObject=new ProcessBuilder(executableFileName,inputFile);
//creating object
File absoluteDirectory = new File(DirectoryPath);
//Assinging 
processBuilderObject.directory(absoluteDirectory);
//starting process
processBuilderObject.start();
//
//processBuilderObject.wait();
 }
```

Step 4:

once `.exe` process was done, then only next Iteration will be start. That means we need to monitor `.exe` process,whether is it done or not.

for integration, I wrote the following function name as `Integration`.

```
  public void Integration(String fileType,String sourcePath,String directoryPath,String executableName,String inputFileName)throws IOException
  {
    //created object for Class
    ExternalFileExecutions ExternalFileExecutionsObject=new ExternalFileExecutions();
    //calling Method from class object
    List<File> finalListNames=ExternalFileExecutionsObject.ListOfFileNames(sourcePath,fileType);
    for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < finalListNames.size(); fileIndex++) 
    {
        //Copy and pasting file from SourcePath to destination Path
        ExternalFileExecutionsObject.FileMoving(
                                                    finalListNames.get(fileIndex),
                                                    directoryPath,
                                                    inputFileName
                                                );
        //Form here,.exe process will be start
        ExternalFileExecutionsObject.ExeternalFileProcessing(directoryPath,executableName,inputFileName);
    }
 }
```

I called these, `Integration` function in my `main()` in the following way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
//created object for Class
ExternalFileExecutions ExternalFileExecutionsObject=new ExternalFileExecutions();
ExternalFileExecutionsObject.Integration(
                                            ".txt",
                                            "C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/copy",
                                            "C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rods",
                                            "ThMapInfratab1-2.exe",
                                            "TMapInput.txt"
                                        );
 }
```

If you observer, my code,every thing was done except `.exe` monitoring,whether is it completed or not.Once first iteration process was done then it allows next Iteration.In second Iteration again `.exe` will be process.it just like `queue`.

Actually I never work on `Java`,but using `stackoverflow` I wrote the above functions. Now I want to fix `.exe` monitoring.

I didn't found anything.

can anyone help me.

I hope, you guys understand what I am facing.

Thanks

Comment: sorry but we will not wirte your code. try something and if you have problems, ask us

Comment: @PhilippSander I wrote two functions. but I am facing some problems so I will tell you  with in 1 hour.

Comment: @PhilippSander I posted the following question. can you check it once.
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808813/how-to-return-array-values-as-a-output-to-a-method-in-java`

Comment: @PhilippSander sorry far late, I Modified my question with some functions.can you check it once.

Comment: @PhilippSander Again I modified my question with one more function.can you check it once.

Answer (score 2):

For running an external process (a `.exe` program in this case), forget about `Runtime.exec()`. Instead use [ProcessBuilder](http://javapapers.com/core-java/os-processes-using-java-processbuilder/); the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) states that it's the preferred way to start up a sub-process these days.

Comment: Lopez I modified my question.can you check it once.

Comment: Lopez I modified my question. can You check it once.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this quick tutorial over running .exe from java. It should be sufficient (4pages)

http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1

example

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GoodWindowsExec
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {


        try
        {            


            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

            Process proc = rt.exec("cmd.exe /C ping"); // executing ping through commandshell of windows

            proc.getErrorStream() // errorstream

            proc.getInputStream()  // outputstream


            int exitVal = proc.waitFor(); // wait till process ends    
        } catch (Throwable t)
          {
            t.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Runtime.exec()` is for practical purposes deprecated. Nowadays the correct way to run external processes is using `ProcessBuilder`, see my answer.

Comment: Sorry Right Now I don't have `.exe` file. I will tell you,in between time I will read tutorial, what you suggested.
tell me one thing, Where will I need to mention my `.exe` file path in your code.

Comment: Either use the full path of the program or use an .exec() with different parameters.
Or use, as Oscar Lopez, suggested ProcessBuilder. It looks like it makes it easier for use to manage ;)

Comment: @user1394628 My `ThMapInfratab1-2.exe` is in under `C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod's` directory.Know I want to Run this `.exe` file.I tried in the following way.
`Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            String[] filePath={"C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod's"};
            Process proc = rt.exec("ThMapInfratab1-2.exe",filePath);`.
But it's not working.How can I fix this.

Comment: I think it was like this for me:
File dir = new file("C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod\'s")
rt.exec("ThMapInfratab1-2.exe", null, dir);

Comment: @user1394628 I tried in the following way, still I am getting the following error.
`File filePath=new File("C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod/");            
            Process proc = rt.exec("ThMapInfratab1-2.exe", null, filePath);`.
How can I fix this.

Comment: @user1394628 I fix problem using `ProcessBuilder()`.but I didn't get How to set Queue(once first Iteration done,then only it allows to another Iteration). I Modified my question with more functions. can you check it once.

Comment: Have you tried 'waitFor()'? 'processBuilderObject.start().waitFor()' or 'Process p = processBuilderObject.start(); p.waitFor()'