# How to copy file from directory to another Directory in Java

Tags: java

I am using `JDK 6`.

I have 2 folders names are `Folder1` and `Folder2`.

`Folder1` have the following files

```
TherMap.txt

TherMap1.txt

TherMap2.txt
```

every time `Folder2` have only one file with name as `TherMap.txt`.

What I want,

copy any file from `folder1` and pasted in `Folder2` with name as `TherMap.txt`.If already `TherMap.txt` exists in `Folder2`, then delete and paste it.

for I wrote the following code.but it's not working

```
public void FileMoving(String sourceFilePath, String destinationPath, String fileName) throws IOException {
    File destinationPathObject = new File(destinationPath);
    File sourceFilePathObject = new File(sourceFilePath);
    if ((destinationPathObject.isDirectory()) && (sourceFilePathObject.isFile()))
    //both source and destination paths are available 
    {
        //creating object for File class
        File statusFileNameObject = new File(destinationPath + "/" + fileName);
        if (statusFileNameObject.isFile())
        //Already file is exists in Destination path
        {
            //deleted File
            statusFileNameObject.delete();
            //paste file from source to Destination path with fileName as value of fileName argument
            FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFilePathObject, statusFileNameObject);
        }
        //File is not exists in Destination path.
        {
            //paste file from source to Destination path with fileName as value of fileName argument
            FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFilePathObject, statusFileNameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

I call the above function in `main()`

```
 //ExternalFileExecutionsObject is class object
 ExternalFileExecutionsObject.FileMoving(
            "C:/Documents and Settings/mahesh/Desktop/InputFiles/TMapInput1.txt",
            "C:/Documents and Settings/mahesh/Desktop/Rods",
            "TMapInput.txt");
```

While I am using `FileUtils` function, it showing error so I click on error, automatically new package was generated with the following code.

```
 package org.apache.commons.io;
 import java.io.File;
 public class FileUtils {
    public static void copyFile(File sourceFilePathObject,
        File statusFileNameObject) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
 }
```

my code not showing any errors,even it's not working.

How can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying files from one directory to another in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java)

Comment: You have not downloaded and added a reference to ApacheCommons.  Instead, you have just created a method stub in your project that matches the copyFile schema.  If you intend to follow the ApacheCommons solution, you will have to download the whole library and add a reference to it.

Comment: In addition, you will need to delete the copyFile method stub you created or else you will have an ambiguous method call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Apache Commons` [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)
`FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, desc);`

Comment: I am new to java side, so can you explain clearly. Where I need to change my code

Comment: I want to copy one file from one directory to another directory. I don't want  to copy and paste directory.and also I don't want to copy and paste all the files at a time.

Comment: @All If anyone understood this answer, let me know. I am using `JRE 6`.

Comment: @urtrulyfriend: Do you have Commons IO jar in your classpath. if not download is available here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

Comment: I downloaded and unzip the folder and added `commons-io-2.4.jar` through `AddExternalJars` option.
still it's not working.I used `CopyFile[]`. is it right.

Comment: @urtrulyfriend, now delete your generated FileUtils class (which is shown in lower part of your question), and see if you can reference Commons FileUtils class the way stated in my answer

Comment: It's working great @Learner, Thanks for your answer. you know this is my second Java method in my life.Actually I am working on `Wolfram Mathematica`. we don't have any function for monitoring execution file in Mathematica. that's why I started to write Java code. that entire details explained in the following link.
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804790/how-can-i-monitor-external-files-in-java`.If you anything about that suggest me.

Comment: Very happy that it worked for you. For a starter, you're doing a good job and using right resources. Way to go!

Comment: can you check the following link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826732/how-to-run-exe-file`.@Learner

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because in order to use the ApacheCommons solution you will have to download the ApacheCommons library found here:

http://commons.apache.org/

and add a reference to it.

Since you are using JRE 6 you can't use all the NIO file utilities, and despite everyone loving Apache Commons as a quick way to answer forum posts, you may not like the idea of having to add that utility on just to get one function.  You can also use this code that uses a transferFrom method without using ApacheCommons.

```
public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
  if (!destFile.exists()) {
    destFile.createNewFile();
  }
  FileInputStream fIn = null;
  FileOutputStream fOut = null;
  FileChannel source = null;
  FileChannel destination = null;
  try {
    fIn = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
    source = fIn.getChannel();
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
    destination = fOut.getChannel();
    long transfered = 0;
    long bytes = source.size();
    while (transfered < bytes) {
      transfered += destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
      destination.position(transfered);
    }
  } finally {
    if (source != null) {
      source.close();
    } else if (fIn != null) {
      fIn.close();
    }
    if (destination != null) {
      destination.close();
    } else if (fOut != null) {
      fOut.close();
    }
  }
}
```

When you upgrade to 7, you will be able to do the following

```
public static void copyFile( File from, File to ) throws IOException {
    Files.copy( from.toPath(), to.toPath() );
}
```

reference:

https://gist.github.com/mrenouf/889747

[Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java)