# How to run .exe file?

Tags: java, java-ee-6

Actually I am working `Wolfram Mathematica`,we don't have any functions for running external programs, so I want to do this App using Java technology.

In my organization, `C` developing team, developed one Application and given to us in a `.exe` format.Know I want to run that `.exe` file from `Java`.

I have a `.exe` name as `ThMapInfratab1-2.exe` under `C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod's` directory.

once we run the `.exe` file, automatically I takes `.txt` file as a input name as `TherInput.txt` from the same directory (`C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod's`)

For my conformation, I run the `ThMapInfratab1-2.exe` file manually using command prompt in the following way.it's working great.

```
 C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\Desktop\Rod's>ThMapInfratab1-2.exe
```

Finally `.exe` file exports t `.txt` files as a output into same directory(`C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod's`).

These same thing, I want to do using `Java`.can you explain with my directories.

For this, I wrote the following code but it's not working.

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class ProcessBuilderSample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder(
                "C:\\Users\\Infratab bangalore\\Desktop\\Rod's\\ThMapInfratab1-2.exe")
                .start();
    }
}
```

If anyone knows,suggest me.

Thanks.

.

Comment: Flagged as a duplicate question to the link WYSIWYG pointed out.

Comment: @All Guys I modified my question. so can you check it once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute exec() method of Runtime that returns Process instance or use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class methods.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec("C:\\Users\\Infratab Bangalore\\Desktop\\Rod's\\ThMapInfratab1-2.exe");
```

You can use ProcessBuilder as

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
 File log = new File("log");
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
 pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
 Process p = pb.start();
 assert pb.redirectInput() == Redirect.PIPE;
 assert pb.redirectOutput().file() == log;
 assert p.getInputStream().read() == -1;
```

Comment: I modified my question, can you check it once.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Infratab Bangalore\\Desktop\\Rod's\\ThMapInfratab1-2.exe");
```

Comment: by mistake i changed your link inside exec method. (Apologies)

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I wrote code in the following way. it's not working.`import java.io.IOException;
public class ExeProcess
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
     Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod's>ThMapInfratab1-2.exe");
    }
}`.I am getting the following error `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:/Users/Infratab": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: mind the file separators

Comment: @MaVRoSCy my folder name is `Infratab Bangalore`

Comment: whatever... the problem is that you are using / instead of  \\

Comment: You mean, Am I need to use like this, `C:\\Users\\Infratab Bangalore\\Desktop\\Rod's\\ThMapInfratab1-2.exe`.

Comment: of course you need to use that

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Still it showing same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\Desktop\Rod's>ThMapInfratab1-2.exe");
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile - Illegal escape character