# How can I fix problems while running .exe file

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a `ThMapInfratab1-2.exe`file under `C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\Desktop\Rod` directory. I executed in command prompt in the following way.it's working fine.

```
 C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\Desktop\Rod>ThMapInfratab1-2.exe TMapInput.txt
```

I want to do same procedure using `Java` technology. using `StackOverFlow` guys,I tried in 2 ways.

Case 1:

Using `getRuntime()`.

```
   import java.util.*;
   import java.io.*;
   public class ExeProcess
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    File filePath=new File("C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod");
    String[] argument1  = {"TMapInput.txt"};
    Process proc = rt.exec("ThMapInfratab1-2.exe", argument1, filePath);
}
}
```

Case 2:

Using `ProcessBuilder`

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 public class ProcessBuilderSample {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
 {
  String executable = "ThMapInfratab1-2.exe";
  String argument1  = "TherInput.txt";
  File workingDirectory = new File("C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod");

  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(executable, argument1);
  pb.directory(workingDirectory);
  pb.start();     
 }
 }
```

in both cases, I am getting the following error.

Error:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ThMapInfratab1-2.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\Desktop\Rod"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at ProcessBuilderSample.main(ProcessBuilderSample.java:16)
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 2 more
```

I did't figure out, what's the problem. can anyone suggest me.

I am using `jre 7`.

Thanks

Comment: maybe a typo in your path?

Comment: @PhilippSander I tried with following ways also. 1. `C:\\Users\\Infratab Bangalore\\Desktop\\Rod` and 2. `C://Users//Infratab Bangalore//Desktop//Rod`

Comment: hmmm sounds like a permission issue. what OS are you using?

Comment: @PhilippSander I am using `Windows 7`.

Comment: @PhilippSander I placed my `Rod` folder in `E` directory. and I changed file path in my code still  it's not working.I tried `notepad.exe` with case 1 it's working fine.it's not working with case 2. I installed Putty.exe under `C:/Program Files/PuTTY`. I tried `putty.exe` with case 1.This also not working. I think only inbuild `.exe` files only working.

Comment: I used file path like this `C:/Windows/System32/`. While I am tried with `Notepad.exe`.It's working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use this :

```
import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 public class ProcessBuilderSample {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
 {
  String executable = "ThMapInfratab1-2.exe";
  String argument1  = "TherInput.txt";
  File workingDirectory = new File("C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod");

  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c","start" ,executable, argument1);
  pb.directory(workingDirectory);
  pb.start();     
 }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,it's working great. can you explain first 3 arguments of the following statement.
`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c","start" ,executable, argument1);`

Comment: see this : [What does cmd /C mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515309/what-does-cmd-c-mean)

Comment: and for "start", i think it's just program title, you can alter it.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
pb.directory(workingDirectory);
```

specifies only the working directory. This is not the directory where the executable `ThMapInfratab1-2.exe` is to be searched for. But it is the directory where the file you specify as argument `TMapInput.txt` is to be searched for. Since `TMapInput.txt` is not an absolute path, your programm will then search for that file relativly to the working directory.

To solve you problem you need to specify the full path for the excecutable:

```
String executable = "C:\\Users\\Infratab Bangalore\\Desktop\\Rod\\ThMapInfratab1-2.exe";
String argument1  = "TherInput.txt";
File workingDirectory = new File("C:\\Users\\Infratab Bangalore\\Desktop\\Rod");
```

Or if you do not need to the location `C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\Desktop\Rod`  just pass the absolute path of the file too and remove the statement `pb.directory(workingDirectory);`:

```
String executable = "C:\\Users\\Infratab Bangalore\\Desktop\\Rod\\ThMapInfratab1-2.exe";
String argument1  = "C:\\Users\\Infratab Bangalore\\Desktop\\Rod\\TherInput.txt";
```

Alternatively you could extend your `PATH` environment variable to include the location `C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\Desktop\Rod`. In this case the programm will run just fine as you posted it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I don't want to pass any arguments, because my `.exe` file takes automatically. For this I tried following code. it showing error.

Comment: I have a one more doubt also,I don't want to pass any argument. So I wrote the following code.it's not working because I didn't use `pb.directory(workingDirectory);`
My code:
`public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
 {
  String executable = "C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod/ThMapInfratab1-2.exe";
  //String argument1  = "TherInput.txt";
  //File workingDirectory = new File("C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod");
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(executable);
//  pb.directory(workingDirectory);
  pb.start();     
 }`compulsory we need to mention`directory()`

Comment: @urtrulyfriend Since you have specified the absolute path for `ThMapInfratab1-2.exe` your java program should be finding the exe but if that exe is coded to look for the file using only its name `TherInput.txt` then it will not find it. In that case you have to provide the working directory which has to point to the location where the file is. That is exactly what setting the `working directory` in ProcessBuilder is for!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I Modified my previous question.Actually I am working on `Wolfram Mathematica`.Because we faced one problem in`Mathematica`.so we decided to work on `Java`.But I never work on `Java`.Regarding my problem I posted the following link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804790/how-can-i-monitor-external-files-in-java`. Because of this problem I am working from yesterday. Finally using `StackOverFlow`  guys I wrote 4 functions.Still I need to figure out. That one I mention in above link.can you check it once.